# Dealing with "Untrusted connection" in FireFox using WebDriver

Tags: c#, firefox, testing, webdriver

I faced an issue with ff tests, when it tries to open the https page I get an "Untrusted connection" message and test fails. I tried many walkarounds, such as

```
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        bool AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        capability.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile);
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
        Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

or I tried to use a default profile, where tested site added to exceptions.
Also, I added domen to trusted

> Preferences > Edit > Advanced > Encryption > View Certificates >
>   Servers

when webdriver opens browser domen is in trusted, but still I retrieve an error message.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the FirefoxDriver like you do, it creates a temporary profile for the session. What you want to do is create a new profile, add the site and the certificate to the exception list and use that profile with the ForefoxDriver.

Comment: Like I said before "I tried to use a default profile, where tested site added to exceptions", site was added to exceptions. What I'm trying to say is that I do the same as you said, but used not a new profile, but default. This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your script

```
  ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
  System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile","Selenium"); //name of your profile
  String browserProfile = System.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile");
  FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile(browserProfile); 
  profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(false); 
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```